# Getting list of all applied discounts in magento cart

Tags: magento, discount, magento-1.9

I am writing am extension for my magento shop which basically gives 5% discount to all newsletter subscribed customers. the extension is working but now problem is it doesn't show the promotion code discounts entered by customers.
I am using this code to get discount:

```
$address->setDiscountAmount($total - $discountAmount);
$address->setDiscountDescription("5% Discounted Subtotal");
$address->setBaseDiscountAmount($total - $discountAmount);
```

I was wondering if there is any magento method or functions which gets an array of all applied discounts for the cart.
Or if anyone can tell me where can i find list of all the available functions in magento.

Comment: You can set the `promotion code` in registry and save it customer wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get total discount for all the items in the cart, you can try this,

```
$quote2 = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$discountTotal = 0;
foreach ($quote2->getAllItems() as $item){
    $discountTotal += $item->getDiscountAmount();
}
```